# how can i show android:icon in android menu ( android studio)

Tags: android, menu, icons

i create application with default android studio menu, but when i change default icon with my drawable icon this circle icon is not visible.

my problem is how can i show icon in my android menu.

I used this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_radio" android:icon="@drawable/radio_icon"
        android:title="Radio" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tv" android:icon="@drawable/tv_icon"
        android:title="TV" />
</group>

<item android:title="Autre">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@drawable/mail_icon"
            android:title="Send" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_like" android:icon="@drawable/heart_icon"
            android:title="Rate Me" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_recording" android:icon="@drawable/cloud_icon"
            android:title="Recording" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_close" android:icon="@drawable/power_icon"
            android:title="Close" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

and i don't show icone

[image]

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you activity Where you have used NavigationView use this one line of code. doing this may solve your problem.

```
setItemIconTintList(null);
```

in your Activity

```
mNavigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
mNavigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
```